# Access Microsoft Outlook to print the List of members

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Please advice how to get the following

1. From Microsoft outlook
2. Type SOMETHING in the “search address books”
3. Click properties
4. In the Members list we see all the **members names**

The target is to print all the **members names** to a file.

How to do this task with VB script or **with any other Code**?

**example:**

I found this, but I not understand how to set my distribution list in the VB code to print the distribution list members

For example If I have the distribution list **MY_HOME**
how do I insert the **MY_HOME** in the VB code to print all members?

```
Const olFolderContacts = 10

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set colContacts = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items
intCount = colContacts.Count

For i = 1 To intCount
    If TypeName(colContacts.Item(1)) = "DistListItem" Then
        Set objDistList = colContacts.Item(i)
        Wscript.Echo objDistList.DLName
        For j = 1 To objDistList.MemberCount
            Wscript.Echo objDistList.GetMember(j).Name & " -- " & _
             objDistList.GetMember(j).Address
        Next 
        Wscript.Echo
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve / Recipient.AddressEntry.Members.

UPDATE:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNamespace.Logon
set objRecip = objNamespace.CreateRecipient("MY_HOME")
if objRecip.Resolve Then
  set objMembers = objRecip.AddressEntry.Members
  if not (objMembers Is Nothing) Then
    for each objMember in objMembers
      Wscript.Echo objMember.Name & " : " & objMember.Address
    next
  end If
End If
```

Comment: please can you give me example for that - I am very new in VB script

Comment: I dont have code , I serach for some VB script code in google that will print members list , but until now without success

Comment: So what would you script do? How would it run? People here can help you write a script, but they cannot write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Actually I want to print some distribution list
For example if the distribution list called – MY_HOME
The VB script will read the MY_HOME distribution list and will print all the members in the MY_HOME distribution list

Comment: Hi Dmitry - I add example in my question , please advice how to set my distribution list as MY_HOME in the VB code ? or maybe need to change some other lines?